# Nuget Reinstalling Packages - updating incorrect packages folder

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget

In my projects folder root, I have a packages folder that is utilized by various web applications at C:/Projects/packages.  All application references that point to this folder work fine.

However, with a new application, when I pulled the latest code, all references expect the packages folder to live at the solution level - C:/Projects/CompanyName/Apps/SolutionFolder/packages.

When I pull latest, this folder is not included (it's never checked in to subversion) so I have missing references when I first open a project up. However, when I try to build, it doesn't pull the latest for these packages and of course, doesn't compile.  When I run Update-Package -reinstall, it will update the packages IN C:/Projects/packages, and it WILL NOT create the packages folder at the solution level.

I've confirmed that I have the packages.config in each project in the solution and that each project expects that the assemblies will be housed in the packages folder at that level.  What's weird is that after I run the -reinstall, these hintpaths in the project files will actually point to the C:/Projects/packages folder and the assembly references will resolve...but only for 3rd party packages and NOT for our in-house built packages.

Does anyone know why this occurs?  The solution has been to get a copy of the packages folder that a coworker is using and paste that into the solution folder but that doesn't solve the problem if it occurs again.

Comment: Are you using NuGet.config anywhere to specify a custom path for your packages?

Comment: Yes, all the web applications that reference C:/Projects/packages specify a repositoryPath matching this location. However, the new application I'm working with DOES NOT specify this repo path. It simply specifies the disableSourceControlIntegration key.

Comment: Just wondering if the NuGet.config file inheritance is affecting things. If the NuGet.config file which defines the repositoryPath is below the other project in the directory structure then it may be picking up that value. I would try defining the repositoryPath in the NuGet.config file that does not have it defined, if possible. The inheritance is document here - http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/nuget-config-file

Comment: ah ha! I specify this C:/Projects/packages path in my nuget.config file in appdata. removing this setting results in packages being installed in the appropriate spot (at the solution level) on build. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per @MattWards [link](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/nuget-config-file) I checked the nuget.config file in appdata, which specified this C:/project.packages path. After removing this setting and building my solution, the packages folder was added to the solution level and everything worked.